# Declaração if vazia em função

Tags: python, python-3.x, funções, if

É possível criar uma função que termine com um if statement vazio e permita que o código que chamou essa função determine a ação do if?

Exemplo:

```
def if():
    if x>6:


x = input("Valor de x")

if()
    print(x)

x = input("Valor de x")  

if()
    x = x*2
```

Neste código o if() criaria a condição if x>6 e o que segue criaria a ação caso a condição seja atendida, porém ele não funciona pois o "if x>6:" expecta algo subsequente.

Se não, existe outra forma de criar um mecanismo que funcione do mesmo modo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não como vocẽ está imaginando - qualquer comando que termina com `:` no Python cria um bloco - e esse bloco tem que ter expressões e comandos, senão é um erro de sintaxe.

**Atualização**: 
passar funções como parâmetro, como descrevo abaixo, exceto em linguagens especializadas chamadas "funcionais" pode ser considerado um pouco avançado. Para quem está aprendendo o básico de uma linguagem principalmente imperativa, como o Python, o melhor é que sua função faça todos os testes que podem ser tão complicados quanto se queira, e retorne um valor True ou False - você faz um `if` no ponto em que chama a função e testa o retorno da mesma - principalmente se quer alterar variáveis locais.

(essa é a ideia principal na resposta do  Maniero, que escreveu independente da minha resposta original, que continua abaixo)

Quando não queremos fazer nada no bloco (por exemplo, as vezes num `except:` , para um rro que sabemos que pode acontecer e não é algo essencial), existe o comando `pass`, que simplesmente não faz nada.

No entanto, em Python, funções são objetos como qualquer outro, e podem ser passadas como parâmetros. Então dá para fazer algo como o que você quer passando como parâmetro para a primeira função uma segunda função que faz a ação desejada.

```
def if_(x, func):
    if x>6:
       return func(x)
    return None

def imprime(x):
    print(x)

def x_quadrado(x):
    return x ** 2


x = int(input("Valor de x"))

if_(x, imprime)

x = input("Valor de x")  

quadrado = if_(x, x_quadrado)
print(quadrado)
```

Note que nesse caso, como não estamos chamando as fuções "imprime" e "x_quadrado" na hora de chamar a função, não usamos parenteses após seu nome: o Python trata as funções exatamente como trata qualquer variável.

Dentro da função, o segundo parâmetro tem o nome `func` e vai receber a função passada. Só quando fazemos `func(...)` é que a função é de fato chamada.

Além disso, para tarefas muito curtas, existe a palavra chave `lambda` que permite escrever "mini-funções" em uma única linha de código, dentro de uma expressão. Uma função criada com lambda não precisa ter um nome em uma variável e pode ser declarada direto na chamada a primeira função. Lambdas não precisam do comando "return": elas tem uma única expressão e seu resultado é que é retornado. Então dá pra escrever assim:

```
if_(x, lambda x: print(x))
```

Mas essa forma por vezes diminui a legibilidade - na maior parte dos casos o recomendado é criar uma outra função com `def` mesmo.

Answer (score 4):

Acho que é isto que deseja.

```
def filtro(p):
    if p > 6:
        return True
    return False

x = int(input("Valor de x"))
if filtro(x): print(x)
x = int(input("Valor de x"))
if filtro(x): x = x * 2
print(x)
x = int(input("Valor de x"))
if filtro(x): x = x * 2
print(x)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/IUPK5f). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vgfotyfr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/Validation2.py).

Poderia usar `lambda`, mas acho que não é o mais adequado para este caso, especialmente quando tem que executar uma ação com efeito colateral como na segunda ação que atribui valor para a variável.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. O 'return false' em filtro(p) é necessário?